# How to store a list as a dictionary - python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I know how to store in a list but how do I store these values as a dictionary instead?

```
    items = []
    for a in range(10):
        items.append([])
        for b in range(10):
            if function() == condition:
                items[a].append(WRONG)
    for a,b in oldItems:
        items[a][b] = RIGHT
```

So far I have come to the conclusion that I could store items as `items = {}` but I don't know how to duplicate the `.append` method with a dictionary. Nor do I know how to access a dictionary like `items[a][b]` does. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring a dictionary:

```
dictionary = {}
```

Adding to a dictionary:

```
dictionary[newkey] = newvalue
```

Accessing a dictionary:

```
print (dictionary[newkey])
```

Returns:

```
newvalue
```

Answer (score 4):

One major difference between a dictionary and a list is that dictionaries have "keys" while lists have "indices". So instead of `.append()`, you need to assign the value to a specific key, like this:

```
items = {}
for a in range(10):
    items[a] = []    # items[a] creates a key 'a' and stores an empty list there
    for b in range(10):
        if function() == condition:
            items[a].append(WRONG)
for a, b in oldItems:
    items[a][b] = RIGHT
```

Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) on `dict`, as well as some tutorials on beginner Python programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #take input from User
    N = int(raw_input())

 #declare a dictionary
    dictn = {}

    for _ in range(N):
            SplitInput = raw_input().split()
            keyValue, ListValues = SplitInput[0], SplitInput[1:]
            ListValues = map(float, ListValues)
            dictn[keyValue] = ListValues
    print dictn

    input:
    3
    FirstKey 11 12 13
    SecondKey 45 46 47
    ThirdKey 67 68 69

    Output:
    {'SecondKey': [45.0, 46.0, 47.0], 'ThirdKey': [67.0, 68.0, 69.0], 'FirstKey': [11.0, 12.0, 13.0]}
```